# flutter buildapp bundle failed

Tags: flutter, dart, deployment, release

I am trying to releas my app on play store and the command flutter build appbundle failed:

thi was the error:

```
Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: IconTreeShakerException: ConstFinder failure: ../../Documents/FlutterDevelopment/SDKS/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/const_finder.dart.snapshot: Error: Error when reading '../../Documents/FlutterDevelopment/SDKS/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/const_finder.dart.snapshot': No such file or directory


To disable icon tree shaking, pass --no-tree-shake-icons to the requested flutter build command


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/***/Documents/FlutterDevelopment/SDKS/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1157

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command '/Users/***/Documents/FlutterDevelopment/SDKS/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

this is the key.properties:

keyAlias=upload
storeFile=../app/upload-keystore.jks

And I have my upload-keystone.jks file in android/app

Here is the build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}




android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "**"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }


}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried running flutte clean and flutter pub get before building but its the same result, I was flowing heyflutters youtube tutorial word for word.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue when I execute `flutter build ios` after removed `/path/to/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts` directory.

In my case, `const_finder.dart.snapshot` has been revived by execute `flutter build ios` after removed `/path/to/flutter/bin/cache` directory (not only `/path/to/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts` but entire `/path/to/flutter/bin/cache`.

Same solution described here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67153#issuecomment-1112562064